# Not able to complete installation of workflow manager

Tags: 2013, workflow-manager, workflow-manager-farm

When I am typing this command `Register-SPWorkflowService` in the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell , I get an error message saying that this command is not recognized.

I also ran this `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` but again the same error message

I am running the powershell window as administrator.

I am also not able to see the command when ran this command `Get-Command *register*`

What can be the issue here ?

Screenshot:[image]

Comment: What do you get when you run: get-command -module microsoft.sharepoint.powershell (that should output hundreds of cmdlets (779 on my machine)) In other words, is it just this command that's missing, or do you not have access to any of them?

Answer (score 3):

if you do a get-command from the powershell do you see it listed in there similar to this screenshot:

[image]

if not then follow these process

Configuring SharePoint 2013 to support workflow Management Service
y default, in SharePoint 2013, Workflow Manager Service is not configured. Workflow Manager Service has to be downloaded, installed and configured manually before it can be used in SP 2013. Here is a step by step walkthrough.

Step 1: Open Microsoft Web Platform Installer
[image]

My version of WPI is 4.5
[image]

Step 2: Search for Workflow. You will get the below list
[image]

Step 3: Select Workflow Manger 1.0, click Add and then "Install"
[image]

Step 4:  Click on "I Accept"
[image]

Step 5:  Click on "Continue"

[image]

Step 6:  Click on "Continue"
[image]

Step 7:  Click on "Configure Workflow Manager with Custom Settings"
[image]

Step 8:  Click on all " Test  Connection" buttons

[image]

Step 9:  Supply User details and Passwords 
[image]

Step 10:  Accept the defaults  and check "Allow Workflow management over HTTP on this computer" option as your system is not configured for HTTPS.
[image]

Step 11:  Next task is Service Bus configuration. 
[image]

Step 12:  Do test connections and select "use the same account" and "use the same certificate" options.
[image]

[image]

Step 13:  Accept the summary screen

[image]

Step 14:  Now, installation in progress and it will take couple of minutes
[image]

[image]

Step 15:  Installation complete 
[image]

[image]

Step 16:  Check Application Pool "WorkflowMgmtPool" running or not 
[image]

Step 17:  Check web site "Workflow Management  Site" running or not 
[image]

Step 18:  Install Cumulative updates. First install cumulative update of Service Bus
[image]

[image]

[image]

Step 19:  Install Workflow Manager 1.0 Cumulative Update 1
[image]

[image]

Step 20: DO IISRESET
[image]

Step 21:  Workflow Service Status will still remain "Not Connected"
[image]

Step 22:  You need to register "Workflow Manger". For that, Open Management Shell as Administrator

[image]

Step 23:  Give this command Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "http://xxxx" -WorkflowHostUri "http://xxxx:12291" -AllowOAuthHttp

[image]

Step 24:  Refresh the page. Your Workflow Service Status is "connected" now.

[image]

Step 25:  You can also verify this using SharePoint Designer. For that, connect to the server

[image]

Step 26:  Select Workflow, click on List workflow. Check the platform type by clicking on Platform Type Selection box. You will see both SharePoint 2010 Workflow and SharePoint 2013 Workflow.

[image]

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps for installation. But still I am not able to run the command `Register-SPWorkflowService`

Comment: Request you Please attach screenshot. this will help to analyze better

Comment: As I see in powershell it was "Method 'Upgrade' in type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServiceApplicationProxy' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Wor Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' does not have an implementation. "  This is issue with upgrade. Please install the update, open up that PS window & you're blissfully error free. Then you will be able to register Workflow Manager.

Comment: I have installed all the updates shown in your answer, but still I am facing the issue. Please tell me which update I have to install.

Comment: Could you please provide your SharePoint build version. To get build version go to CA>Manage servers in the farm

Comment: I hope this is the required info. Configuration database version: 15.0.4701.1000

Comment: You are having March 2015 Patch. for Workflow manager you must have April 2015 that is 15.4711.1001 (KB 2965266). Please install this patch to get your issue resolve. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46574

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of reasons for this situation.

1. You are running the command in the workflow manager pwoershell not SharePoint Powershell. This command run in the SharePoint Powershell windows.
2. You are running this command on the sharepoint server in SharePoint powershell but dont have Workflow manager or client installed on the machine.

Check my post over here:
[SharePoint Server 2016 Troubleshooting - Workflow Manager 1.0 - The Term 'Register-SPWorkflowService' Is Not Recognized](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-server-2016-troubleshooting-workflow-manager-1-0-the-term-regis/)